# How can I select the first option in select with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to select the first option in an html page that is roughly structured like this...

```
<select id="select">
 <option>sjdjdjs</option>
 <option>sjdjdjs</option>
 <option>sjdjdjs</option>
</select>
```

I've tried with options on the element and clicking the first index of the array that comes back

await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#select').options[0].click())

it is not selected

Comment: No...they are selecting my the value of the dropdown which I don't have.